# Recursively enumerating all partitions of the number 4 into four ordered numbers?

Tags: algorithm, recursion, language-agnostic

The number of all cases where the value 4 could be assigned to an array of length 4 would be:

```
[4,0,0,0]
[3,1,0,0]
[3,0,1,0]
[3,0,0,1]
[2,2,0,0]
[2,1,1,0]
...
[0,0,0,4]
```

How can I solve this with a recursive function?

I thought it could be easily solved using recursion, but it's too difficult.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an example in JavaScript, implementing the idea shared by templatetypedef:

```js
function f(n, k, i=1){
  if (i == n)
    return [k];
    
  const result = [];
    
  for (let s=0; s<=k; s++)
    f(n, k - s, i + 1).map(comb => result.push([s].concat(comb)));
  
  return result;
}

var n = 4;
var k = 4;

console.log(JSON.stringify(f(n, k)));
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's a different way to see this. Imagine that you have a group of n people who have to split a bill for $k dollars. How would you list all the possible ways those people could split the bill?

One recursive insight you can use is the following. Look at the first person and ask - how much money are they going to pay? If they pay $0, the remaining people have to collectively pay $k. If they pay $1, the remaining people have to collectively pay $k-1. If they pay $2, the remaining people have to collectively pay $k-2. And more generally, if they pay $d, the remaining people have to collectively pay $k - d. So if you have n > 1 people, pick some person (doesn't matter how), then for each amount they could possibly pay, have them pay that amount and the remaining people pay the rest.

The base case for this process is when you're down to one person. If there's just one person and the remaining bill is $k, then they have to pay all $k dollars. There's no choice there.

In pseudocode, this might look like this:

```
SplitTheBill(n people, $k):
    if n == 1, output that the one person pays $k.
    else:
       pick one person p.
       for each amount $d between $0 and $k, inclusive:
           have person p pay $d.
           use SplitTheBill(n - 1 people, $k - $d) to list all ways
               the remaining people can pay the rest of the bill.
```

Translating this logic into code will require you to think through how you track who's spent how much, to determine the right ordering of the people, etc. But hopefully this gives you a sense of how to approach this problem.

Best of luck!